# How do I start postgresql from Docker

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile

I am tying to start a postgresql service during docker build.

In my docker file:

```
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && createdb gis && psql -d gis -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'
```

The output during build:

```
Step 29/29 : RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && createdb gis && psql -d gis -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'
 ---> Running in 7d7848bf2d1a
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server
   ...done.
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Checking the status in the docker container:

```
postgres@16ab935bc857:/$ /etc/init.d/postgresql status
9.5/main (port 5432): down
```

But running the command directly in the docker container does show it ran before and created the container

```
postgres@16ab935bc857:/$ /etc/init.d/postgresql start && createdb gis && psql -d gis -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server                                                                                                                                        [ OK ] 
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "gis" already exists
```

Anybody knows how to properly start the postgresql service **in a Dockerfile**?

**Update**:
My best guess is the following:
Every line in a docker file does simply represent a new bash session, but an analogy with a system shutdown and boot would be more correct. This implies that all commands on the same line (linked with "&&") went through, and I would simply need to do another "postgresql start &&" at the start of the next line, or link the other commands.